# In the template are the attributes in a nest statements accessible by all child statements?

Tags: python, django

For some reason the `q.user` is not flowing through to the inner if statement, I'm guessing the if statement breaks the flow, because `{{ q.user }}` in the second child for loop works

```
{% for q in y %}
    {% for w in yname %}
        {% if w.user == q.user %}
            {{q.user}}<br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit -- please help I dont know why the if statement is failing the following is the out put of the the object in yname and y

```
{% for q in yname %}
    {{ q.user }}   
{% endfor %}
```

test3 user ann

```
{% for w in y %}
    {{ w.user }}        
{% endfor %}
```

ann test3 test3 test3 test3 user test3

---

the if statement below wont become true, can some one tell me why?

```
{% for q in yname %}
    {% for w in y %}
        {% if w.user == q.user %}
            {{w.question}}<br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perhaps the if statement isn't true?

Comment: @SimeonVisser yeah the if statement is isn't true, but i can't figure out why... i edited the question to add more information

Comment: are y and yname coming from the same model?? I tried this out and it works for me

Comment: maybe post your view code that passes y and yname

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have w.user.user, possibly because the query is a tuple.

The yname was a custom list i had made from a django query using for loops, just for your information, in case you were wondering why it didn't need a child